# Azure Data Factory - Import excel file with dynamic range

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I'm very new to ADF using stored procedure. I'm building pipeline to import excel file but some files has column names starting from A4 or A9.

Is there a way to import all files with dynamic range ?

I really appreciate if anybody could help or refer any source to read !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parameterize the **Range** property in the Excel dataset connector and pass the dynamic value from the pipeline as required.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. So for different files, I have to adjust in data_range ?

Comment: yes, you can also create a pipeline parameter and pass the range at runtime.

Comment: Thanks so much. I got it!